# PropertyListEncoder Produces Double the Expected Data

Tags: swift, serialization, codable

I have a codable struct that looks like this:

```
struct Matrix: Codable {
    var values: [Float]
    var rowInds: [Int32]
    var colStarts: [Int]
}
```

The contents of my struct look like this:

```
values.count * 4 [Bytes per Float] -> 26092468
rowInds.count * 4 [Byte per Int32] -> 26092468
colStarts.count * 4 [Bytes per Int] -> 800488
```

This gives a total of `52,985,424 Bytes`.

I then try to convert this into Data using a `PropertyListEncoder` as follows:

```
let propertyEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
propertyEncoder.outputFormat = .binary

let matrix_data = try propertyEncoder.encode(matrix)
print(matrix.count)
```

The result of this call is `113,568,678`. That is exactly `2x` my estimate.

Why do I see the difference between my estimated and actual size?

Have I made an error in my estimate?

Is there some padding added by the `PropertyListEncoder`?

Can I serialize the struct to binary more efficiently?

Comment: Even with the binary format a PropertyList file has a certain overhead. There must be a header to identify the property list format and dictionary keys and the type information must be included, too.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think the header data etc will account for 2x the memory usage. If the file came out 10-20% larger I'd have though that was about right, but double size would suggest something is wrong to me